# Existence of a polish group $G$ such that $G\cong\text{Isom}(G)$.

Tags: descriptive-set-theory

It is known that every polish group is isomorphic to $\text{Isom}(X)$ for some polish space $(X,\tau)$. My question is if there exist some infinite polish group such that $G\cong\text{Isom}(G)$.

Thank you.

Comment: How about the one-element group?  How about improving your wording?  Also tell us that Isom mean isometries if that is what you want, rather than isomorphisms.

Comment: @GEdgar I think that the one element group is not an example, since is not infinite.